# Wrong result when integrating piecewise function in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am starting to use sympy. I computed a convolution, but the result was not correct:

[image]

[image]

This result is wrong: The correct result is

[image]

So what did I do wrong? I had used sympy to integrate piecewise fucntions before, with no problems...

---

The code:

```
from sympy import *
init_session()

f = lambda x: Piecewise( (1 , (x >= -1) & (x <= 1)) , (0 , True) )
Conv = lambda x: integrate( f(x-y)*f(y) , (y, -oo, +oo) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that you did wrong. It's Sympy having an issue with the product of two piecewise expressions. By calling `piecewise_fold(f(x-y)*f(y))` you can see that it does not manage to sort this product out, leaving it as a nested Piecewise construction.

```
Piecewise((Piecewise((1, And(x - y <= 1, x - y >= -1)), (0, True)), And(y <= 1, y >= -1)), (0, True))
```

The symbolic integration routine trips up on this nested thing, which may be worth [filing an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sympy/sympy).

#### Workaround

If you flatten this nested Piecewise by hand, the integration works correctly.

```
g = Piecewise((1, And(x-y <= 1, x-y >= -1, y <= 1, y >= -1)), (0, True))
integrate(g, (y, -oo, +oo))
```

outputs `Min(1, x + 1) - Min(1, x + 1, Max(-1, x - 1))` which is [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20Min(1,%20x%20%2B%201)%20-%20Min(1,%20x%20%2B%201,%20Max(-1,%20x%20-%201))) although perhaps not in the form one would expect.

Comment: It gives an alternate form, however: `-Max(-1, x - 1) + Max(-1, x - 1, Min(1, x + 1))`